# During import, existing keys not being ignored

Tags: python, django

I am using django-import-export to import author name in my project. Is this possible django-import-export ignore the existing key values, because I have large csv file.when I import it,I am getting an error :

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "spm_author_name_key" DETAIL: Key (name)=(Arthur Rachkam) already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post a bit of your code for review? 
Probably you can wrap your import function in `try/except` and you will avoid duplication
Something like this

```
for author in authors_list:
    try:
        create_entry(author)
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

I will improve my answer once you paste here your actual code which makes import. Also please paste full text of your error(without traceback)